# Is CefSharp.OffScreen library compatible with .NET Standard 2.0?

Tags: c#, compatibility, cefsharp, chromium-embedded, .net-standard-2.0

Is CefSharp.OffScreen library compatible with .NET Standard 2.0? Specifically about version 79.1.360.

Also, is there a general way of checking if a particular library is compatible with .NET Standard 2.0?

Comment: general way of checking if a particular library is compatible with .NET Standard 2.0 should be asked as a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you could see at NuGet.org if a package is .NET Standard compatible.

Just go to the Dependencies part. If there is .NET Standard listed, then it compatible. If nothing is listed there - it's a bit unclear - but it's then highly unlikely it supports .NET Standard.

Examples:

#### JSON.NET

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/12.0.3

Supports .NET Standard 1.0+ (and still also .NET Framework 2.0+)

[image]

#### Cefsharp

https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.OffScreen/79.1.360

Doesn't support .NET Standard, but does .NET Core 3!

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Now it's clear for me.
Will upvote as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

CefSharp is incompatible with .Net Standard 2.0

CefSharp is built with VC++ which .Net Core only added support for in version 3.x.

.Net Standard is implemented by .Net Core 2.x

Also VC++ only runs on Windows, Microsoft have said they don't plan to support cross platform.

For reference https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/the-future-of-cpp-cli-and-dotnet-core-3/ for official response from Microsoft.

Comment: You can use `CefSharp` with `.Net Core 3.x`.